# How to to delete a world's data directory on a Bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

In my Minecraft server plugin for Spigot/Bukkit I am trying to delete a world's data directory, but after unloading the world and its chunks, some files and directories can still not be deleted.

Here is the significant portion of my code:

```
Server server = Backup.getPlugin(Backup.class).getServer();
World world = server.getWorld("world");
File active = world.getWorldFolder();

// Unload the world.
server.unloadWorld(world, false);
// Unload the chunks.
Chunk[] chunks = world.getLoadedChunks();
for (Chunk chunk : chunks) {
    chunk.unload(false);
}
ServerManager.deleteDirectory(active);
```

ServerManager.deleteDirectory(File) utilizes Apache's FileUtils.deleteQuietly(File) and works for other features, but fails to delete some files in data directories of recently unloaded worlds, most likely because some files are still used by the server.

My main question: how can I make sure the world data directory is no longer used so it can be deleted?

Comment: Try to use `FileUtils.deleteDirectory(directory)`. If it doesn't work show us the logs. `FileUtils.deleteQuietly` is not throwing any exception so we don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @Squiddie: all players are kicked, but it fails even when no players are online on the entire server. I've also removed the chunk unloading before creating the error log below.

Comment: @SocketByte: Here is the error log: https://pastebin.com/4YS26i62 (And the second one is repeated several times for different chunks.)

Comment: @Gentle153 hmm, it looks like there's a `session.lock` file which is denying any world removal. Try to remove it first from the directory.

Comment: @SocketByte: I've just tried that while the server is offline, but as soon I restart it, a new session.lock is created and the same error happens when trying to unload the world and delete the directory. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default 3 worlds: normal world, nether, and end can NOT be deleted on the fly, however you can delete the additionally added worlds.

For understanding how can you exactly do it, you may take a look at the MultiverseCore plugins source code: https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core

Comment: Thank you! After some more debugging I found out that unloadWorld(worldName) returned false. This explains why. I used this code as part of a plugin to manage backups, including restoring them. I'll add some extra checks to omit the main world (and its alternative dimensions) from the given options and update the documentation to explain why.